# Hibernate as the JPA provider and Bean Validator in TomEE 7

Tags: jpa, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, apache-tomee, tomee-7

**JPA**

Configured **Hibernate 5.2** as JPA implementor in Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.11 (7.0.3) from [this Article](http://in.relation.to/hibernate-orm/#articles) ([TomEE 7 and Hibernate 5.2 persistence.xml](https://fmdojo.wordpress.com/2017/05/07/tomee-7-and-hibernate-5-2-persistence-xml/))

**Bean Validation**

To implement Hibernate Validator as Bean Validator, placed `hibernate-validator-5.4.0.Final.jar`, `hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-5.4.0.Final.jar`, `hibernate-validator-cdi-5.4.0.Final.jar` in <TomEE-Home>/lib folder and removed `bval-core-1.1.2.jar`, `bval-jsr-1.1.2.jar`

But while deploying webapp gives following error:

```
DEBUG: No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
19-May-2017 09:16:14.276 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication CDI Beans module deployment failed
org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: There is more than one Bean with type javax.validation.ValidatorQualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  validator, Bean Owner : [ValidationInterceptor, WebBeansType:INTERCEPTOR, Name:null, API Types:[java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Object,org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]]
found beans: 
Validator, WebBeansType:VALIDATION, Name:null, API Types:[java.lang.Object,javax.validation.Validator], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any] from jar:file:/webserver/tomee/lib/javaee-api-7.0-1.jar!/javax/validation/Validator.class
ValidatorImpl, WebBeansType:THIRDPARTY, Name:null, API Types:[org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl,javax.validation.executable.ExecutableValidator,java.lang.Object,javax.validation.Validator], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,org.hibernate.validator.cdi.HibernateValidator,javax.enterprise.inject.Any] from jar:file:/webserver/tomee/lib/hibernate-validator-5.4.0.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/ValidatorImpl.class
at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:331)
at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:196)
at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:189)
at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:914)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:718)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1298)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1124)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: There is more than one Bean with type javax.validation.ValidatorQualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  validator, Bean Owner : [ValidationInterceptor, WebBeansType:INTERCEPTOR, Name:null, API Types:[java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Object,org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]]
```

How to resolve this problem????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in Hibernate Validator documentation ([here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-getting-started-cdi)), If application runs in an environment which does not provide CDI integration out of the box, you may use the Hibernate Validator CDI portable extension by adding the `hibernate-validator-cdi`

Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.11 (7.0.3) implements CDI with [Apache OpenWebBeans](http://tomee.apache.org/tomcat-cdi.html) out of the box.

Problem resolved after removing the `hibernate-validator-cdi-5.4.0.Final.jar` from `<TomEE>/lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Think it comes from the fact you include hibernate-validator, you can workaround it setting in application.properties (WEB-INF) or conf/system.properties (global):

```
org.apache.bval.cdi.BValExtension.active=false
```

Comment: With a custom cdi extension you can log all Validator beans and therefore know which extensions/classes conflict. Can just need some scanning adjustment.

Comment: Problem solved by removing hibernate-validator-cdi jar